# How to make fat32 partition mounted at startup?

Tags: partitioning, mount, login

I run Ubuntu 10.10 AMD64 and want to ask for suggestion how to make fat32 partition mounted on startup or at login.

I usually have to open nautilus and click on the partition to get it mounted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add it to your `/etc/fstab` file:

`/dev/sdz9 /mount_point vfat rw,noatime,user 0 0`

Just place your partition and mount point info in there.  That should get you going.