# How to move my Home-Directory?

Tags: home-directory

I have three partitions on my netbook:

1. ntfs with windows 7
2. ext 4 with Ubuntu 11 and
3. fat32 for my private data

On the fat32-Partition Ubuntu und Windows 7 should share my private data.

How could I move my home directory with the exiting files to the fat32-partition? And how do I mount this partition permanently as my home-directory?

Many thanks for an helpful answer.

Comment: Shortly, you don't want /home on a fat32 partition. See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/16038

Comment: You may share single folders on the FAT32 partition. See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/34942/3940) on how to automount your partition.

Comment: in a very short comment: you shouldnt and now a days it will probably break your system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my point of view 
please understand the merit and demerit of moving home folder to other file system

> `NTFS` is not suitable for an home partition, there are certain type of file system objects (character devices, named pipes, etc) which are required for certain services but are not supported on `NTFS`. <sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/16055/61218)</sup>

It's not a good idea to have the whole of `/home` in a `fat32 or NTFS` partition because those two Windows filesystems don't support Linux permissions. Also, the /home folder has many hidden files and folders (these have a leading `.` i.e for hidden files) for configuration and I don't know what effect this would have in Vista, or whether Vista would interfere with these..

But what I do is to have a separate NTFS partition for data and set up symlinks from my `/home` in Linux and whatever the equivalent is in Windows (links? shortcuts?  ). So - say I have a 'Music' folder in my NTFS data partition, then I create a symlink called 'Music' in my Linux home and a link called - yes, you've guessed it - 'Music' in Windows My Documents. (I'm using XP.) In fact I also multiboot several Linux distros, so I do the same in each. Whichever distro/OS I'm in I can access the same files from my home folder by double-clicking on the symlinks (which look like folders with bendy arrows in Linux)

If I am wrong correct me

Comment: That seem to be quite good, but how I create this symlinks?

Comment: +1 for symlinks. Simlinks in Windows XP are called junctions. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

Comment: I used Win7. There you can change the path of some folder (like Photos) by right click --> properties --> path. But how does it goes at ubuntu 11.

Comment: Please use blockquote while using part of other user's writing. Thanks

Answer (score -5):

Follow these commands

**usermod -d /home/your_home_directory USERNAME**

**chown -R USERNAME /new_location/your_home_directory**

Comment: You can't chown or usermod on a FAT32 partition