# Moving home/user directory to another drive?

Tags: home-directory, ssd, storage

I'm installing a SSD and to save space I want to move my user folder to another drive, is there a way to do that?

Comment: check this: http://askubuntu.com/q/77412/110096

Comment: No instructions there

Comment: Useful link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive

Comment: can you specify whether your 'other drive' is an internal, mounted harddrive?

Comment: It's an internal mounted SSD

Comment: @zShell were you able to move your home drive to other disk? did you go through my solution? If you are still facing any issue please let me know.

Answer (score 13):

From Terminal type this:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/tmp
```

which will allow you to temporarily mount the new partition, assuming **/sdb1** as new partition for **HOME**.

```
sudo rsync -avx /home/ /mnt/tmp
```

This will copy **HOME** to new location.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home
```

This will mount the new partition as **HOME** and make sure all data is present.

```
sudo umount /home
```

This will unmount the new partion.

```
rm -rf /home/*
```

This deletes the **old HOME**.

To make **HOME** permanent you need to know the **UUID** of the new partition for the `fstab` entry. you can get that by giving command:

```
sudo blkid
```

Note down the **UUID** and use the same to change `fstab` .

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Now add the following at the end.

```
UUID=<noted number from above>    /home    ext4    defaults   0  2
```

*NOTE: You need to select the exact file system that was formatted (for example ext4 as chosen here).*

Now you can restart your computer to see the new HOME.

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the files from your /home to another drive
Change the /etc/fstab entry to point /home to that drive
If you don't how, reply. I will provide a shell script to do that.

Comment: if you got the script I'll take it :)

Comment: May I know how to do it with the script? The above answer didn't work for me. Hoping to try yours.