# How to mount and sdb and move /home directory to sdb

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a question:

when I type the command `sudo lsblk -o`, I get the following:

```
NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL", my outcome looks like this:

NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           119.2G            
├─sda1 vfat     512M /boot/efi  
├─sda2 ext4   110.8G /          
└─sda3 swap       8G [SWAP]     
sdb           931.5G
```

`125G SSD` is my `sda` and `1TB HDD` is my `sdb`.

I was having a problem installing Ubuntu, and I ended up installing the os on both drives. Then I formatted HDD using `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` because I want to boot from `SSD`. So now all my data and partitions are erased in `hdd`.

I want to use `1TB HDD` as my primary storage disk and I think that requires me to move `/home` to `HDD`. Any quick advice on how to do that? And how do you think I should partition my `HDD`?

Comment: Does this help you? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving and http://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive and http://askubuntu.com/questions/239843/moving-home-user-directory-to-another-drive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a new partition on sdb with fdisk. You have to format this partition with ext4 (or any other filesystem type you want).

To move all the data I recommend you to boot from a LiveCD/LiveUSB. Mount sda2 in /mnt/sda2 and sdb1 in /mnt/sdb1. Then copy all the data from /mnt/sda2/home to /mnt/sda2. Finally you have to edit the /mnt/sda2/etc/fstab to automatically mount the /home filesystem:

```
UUID=37xxxxxxx /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

you can get the UUID with blkid

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="379xxxxxx" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0006a6c7-06"
```